# asynchronous postback inside radGrid editForm userControl

Tags: asp.net, telerik, asp.net-ajax

my page (productionEntry.aspx) has a radGrid which contains a radAjaxManager whose settings allow for asynchronous postbacks of the radGrid:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadGridProductionOrders">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGridProductionOrders" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

so RadGridProduictionOrders asynchronously posts back, which is fine.

now, however, the radGrid's editForm is a popup user control, and what i'd like to accomplish is to asynchronously postback some of the user control's content. 
i have tried doing this with a radAjaxManagerProxy and a radAjaxPanel together and with each by itself inside the user control. 
each time the page asynchronously posts back according to the settings in the radAjaxManager from the productionEntry.aspx page.

this was the markup for the radAjaxManagerProxy in the user control. the content that i wanted to post back was inside Panel1:

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy ID="RadAjaxManagerProxy1" runat="server">
<AjaxSettings>
    <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="Panel1">
        <UpdatedControls>
            <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="Panel1" />
        </UpdatedControls>
    </telerik:AjaxSetting>
</AjaxSettings>
```

how do i need to setup the page and/or user control to accomplish what i need?

Answer (score 1):

i contacted telerik regarding this issue, and their response was that it was not possible:

*Although the edit form is in a pop-up window it is still part from the RadGrid. On the server the pop-up control is rendered as part of RadGrid, so it is an integral part of RadGrid. 
Keeping this in mind and knowing that RadGrid is a composite control that should be updated as a whole I am afraid that your requirement could not be achieved with RadAjaxManager. The postback will be always made by RadGrid and you will need to update always the RadGrid which will close and reset the values in the edit form.*

hopefully this will help others down the road...

Answer (score 1):

I know it's been a while, but this is what I built and what I did:

I had a grid as a data entry panel - 3 fixed rows in edit mode.  There was a very likely case that the business would come back and ask for a "show history" view of the same data, so a grid was what I wanted to build (as opposed to a fixed table) to protect myself from change.

Instead of using a GridBoundColumn I used a GridTemplate column with an edititemtemplate as follows:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <telerik:RadTextBox runat="server" ID="Address1" Text='<%#Bind("Address1") %>' OnTextChanged="Address1_OnTextChanged" AutoPostBack="True"></telerik:RadTextBox>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server"><Triggers><asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Address1"/></Triggers></asp:UpdatePanel>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

This allows me to have a simple databind callback per row, per textbox, without causing any graphical changes to the front end or interrupting the user experience.  This creates additional overhead on the page but it should be negligible.

The codebehind looks like:

```
protected void Address1_OnTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Find which row you're on
        var id = ((sender as RadTextBox).Parent.Parent as GridDataItem).GetDataKey("ID");
        //Do whatever you need to do with the data by using the ID to match.
        myList[id].Address1 = (sender as RadTextBox).Text;
    }
```

Edit:  I am using Supervising Presenter pattern where the view is allowed to talk to the model directly in situations where no other logic is involved.  This may require additional overhead if you are doing something different.